# FileHelpers library - Is it possible to change field's date format at runtime?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Using FileHelpers library version 3.0.1 .

Say you define a field to import from a csv file like this :

```
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)] 
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "d-MMMM-yyyy")]
    public DateTime DOB;
```

Now, the csv field is expected to be in the date format "d-MMMM-yyyy", and set at compile time. I have a requirement at runtime to (sometimes) change this format to "d-MMMM-yy".

The format to use depends on the source file - some files have 2 digit years, others have 4 digit years. I will know at program startup which format to use.

Is this possible with FileHelpers ? I suppose I could add a string column like :

```
[FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)] 
[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
public string DOBAsString;
```

, and get FileHelpers to read the data into this field, and convert it to the DOB field myself in a loop. Is there a cleaner way ?

Comment: you can change the value of the FieldConverter attribute at runtime. You can see an example here  http://codinglight.blogspot.in/2008/10/changing-attribute-parameters-at.html

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure if this will work with FileHelpers, because FileHelpers is in charge of creating the instances of the objects in which the field resides. So there seems to be no hook to be able to get an instance of the object (?).

Comment: I understand. If you cannot find a way to solve this issue with FileHelpers, you can still change the attribute at runtime (even if FileHelpers created the instance). You can have this solution as a last resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the `ConverterKind.DateMultiFormat` instead of `ConverterKind.Date`

```
[FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)] 
[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.DateMultiFormat, "d-MMMM-yyyy", "d-MMMM-yy"]
public DateTime DOB;
```

In general, another way of specifying the format at runtime is to use the [runtime classes](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/runtime_classes.html) with a ClassBuilder:

```
FixedClassBuilder cb = new FixedLengthClassBuilder("Customers"); 

cb.AddField("DOB", 8, typeof(DateTime)); 
cb.LastField.Converter.Kind = ConverterKind.Date; 
cb.LastField.Converter.Arg1 = "d-MMMM-yyyy"; // or whatever
cb.LastField.TrimMode = TrimMode.Both; 
cb.LastField.FieldNullValue = DateTime.Now;          

engine = new FileHelperEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());
```